# SMTP not able to send group mail

Tags: java, smtp, windows-server-2008

I need to send a group mail as a part of batch job. I'm using javax.mail package to accomplish this.

```
        Properties m_properties;
        m_properties = new Properties();
        m_properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
        m_properties.put("mail.smtp.port", Integer.toString(26));

        Session m_Session = Session.getDefaultInstance(m_properties);

        Message m_simpleMessage = new MimeMessage(m_Session);
        InternetAddress m_fromAddress = new InternetAddress("me@sample.com");
        InternetAddress m_toAddress = new InternetAddress("group@sample.com");
        m_simpleMessage.setFrom(m_fromAddress);
        m_simpleMessage.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, m_toAddress);
        m_simpleMessage.setSubject(m_subject);
        m_simpleMessage.setContent(m_body, "text/html");

        Transport.send(m_simpleMessage);
```

I'm using a windows server. I installed IIS SMPT server and using it. I have no problem when I send a mail to individual id. But I get an error when trying to send to a group.

**Error :**

This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.
Delivery to the following recipients failed.
    **group@sample.com**

Do I need to configure something in my SMPT server for a group, or do I need to make changes  in my code for allowing to send a group mails.

Comment: It's most likely an issue with the SMTP server. JavaMail doesn't know or care whether an email address is for a single user or a distribution list (group).

Comment: Do I need to configure SMTP such that it knows the group information. If so where can I do.

Comment: Might want to ask on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

The group must exist in the destination server... Does the destination smtp server you are reaching contains the group?

Comment: The group exists in the destination server. I'm able to send test mail manually through my outlook. But, only problem is when I'm doing from my java program. In fact the windows server from which I'm running is sending the delivery failure message.